# execCommand insertHTML causes nested tags

Tags: javascript

I try to make my own WYSIWYG with only one function, add an `<amb>` tag.

My problem is when I call execCommand with insertHTML parameter, my `<amb>` tag is sometimes nested in another but he shouldn't be.

https://jsfiddle.net/dke4x8m9/1/

Steps to reproduce :

1. Paste : `Un avocat mange un avocat.` in grey area.
2. Select the first `avocat` and click on the button `Rendre le mot sélectionné ambigu` : normally the word should appear in red (and Text version is `Un <amb>avocat</amb> mange un avocat`).
3. Select the first word `Un` and click on the button `Rendre le mot sélectionné ambigu` : sometimes its works fine, sometimes if you look the Text version by clicking on `Texte` link you get `<amb><amb>Un</amb>avocat</amb> mange un avocat.`

I would like the `<amb>` tags to contain no space and I would like prevent nesting tags.

Thanks.

Comment: On which browser are your experiencing this issue?

Comment: Chrome, but strangely enough I can't reproduce today unless for step 3 I start selecting the space first and going from right to left.